# Why normal notebook created from script minimizes automatically?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

The code is simple:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/math -script
UsingFrontEnd[FE=$FrontEnd];
Unprotect[$FrontEnd];
$FrontEnd=FE;
nb= NotebookOpen["/home/src/math/test.nb",Visible->True];
Pause[10]
```

But window of Notebook is first minimized, and when clicked (unminimized) then
it immediately minimizes again automaticaly.
When I use Option WindowFrame->ModelessDialog it stays, but I do not know why only in this case. Can anybody explain me a bit this behavior. I'm using math few days and do not know
how to find this in documentation. Thanks.
P.S. I'm using Debian 6 with Gnome and Trial version of Mathematica 8 works well.

Answer (score 2):

When the FrontEnd is launched by the kernel to provide these types of services it is passed "-server" (which is similar to "-nogui").  According to ref/program/mathematica-unix:

> -nogui    prevent the display of any kind of window or dialogues

If you call

```
Developer`InstallFrontEnd["Server"->False]
```

first then you won't get the "-server" behavior which is causing the notebook to automatically minimize.

Comment: @MrWizard I have tested the behavior and updated my response based on my findings.